# How to use vPython into blender?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I want to use [vPython](http://vpython.org/) in blender. Is there any way to implement this into blender? I want to create physics animation. In vPython the arrow vector attached to the moving object is really fantastic which changes according to magnitude and direction of object's property (velocity, force etc. ). I want this in Blender scene. Any help would be appreciated.